# What kind of test to perform for this data?

Tags: t-test

This is example data, but structured similar to my data.
Say, I want to perform a test of gender difference in height.

Let's say I am doing a test of height (cm) across gender, with random samples

| Random Sample # | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| r_sam1 | 150 | 140 |
| r_sam2 | 155 | 145 |
| r_sam3 | 160 | 150 |
| r_sam4 | 165 | 155 |
| r_sam5 | 170 | 160 |

In my mind, it would make sense to use ttest_ind for this. Correct?

Now, let's say instead of random samples, the groupings are age groups

| Age Group | Male | Female |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10-20 | 150 | 140 |
| 21-30 | 155 | 145 |
| 31-40 | 160 | 150 |
| 41-50 | 165 | 155 |
| 51-60 | 170 | 160 |

Can I still use ttest_ind or would I need a different test here because each sample is a different group of people?

Comment: Is each height measured from 1 person or are they aggregated over multiple people?  And what sampling process links the male and female data together on each row?

Comment: Heights were originally sampled periodically for individuals, then averaged for the multiple people in each group. Age groups roughly have the same number of people.

Comment: Is each sample a different group of people in both data sets?  Or does the first data set follow the same people over time?

Comment: Different group of people in both data sets

Comment: In other words, the people in age group 10-20 are only ever in that age group. THere is no data from when those same people move into the 21-30 group

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the model you fit, there's a "lack of variability" problem here.  In all samples the difference between genders is 10cm, so the variance of this effect size is 0.  This will cause any linear model testing for gender differences to choke.  You can interpret this from a mathematical standpoint or take the broader perspective that linear models are only useful when there is uncertainty in the data.

But there are other possible issues too.  In both cases the model would likely be improved by using individual person data rather than aggregated averages.  In the first example it sounds like you are suggesting that the same cohort of individuals were followed over time.  This implies a repeated measures structure with individuals as subjects.  In the second example you have only 1 observation for each age group * gender combination, so to test the effect of gender you would not be able to include a model effect for age group.

Comment: On the "lack of variability" issue...the data I provided above was just example data. My actual data has more variability.

One the "repeated measures" issue...my data is only in the form of the second example. I was using the first example to demonstrate perhaps a more straightforward situation. So I have data of age group, height, and gender. If I did use the individual person data, what test would I then use? Just a linear regression of some sort, or is there some ttest/anova/chi2 type thing that I could use?

Comment: If you have the actual ages of each person then you could run an analysis of covariance (ANCOVA) model with age as the covariate and gender as a fixed effect.  Do the usual verification of equal or variable y-intercepts and slopes.  If you want to keep age as a category then you can do a two-way ANOVA with age and gender as fixed effects, or you could fit a mixed model with gender as a fixed effect and age as a random effect.